# Extjs. Can't catch write event after store.save() with create action

Tags: events, extjs, store, ext-direct

I'm trying to handle event after creating new record to ExtJS store and saving it to server. But I have a problem - write event firing only after update action. Documentation says:

> @event write Fires if the server
>   returns 200 after an
>   Ext.data.Api.actions CRUD action.
>   Success of the action is determined in
>   the result['successProperty']property
>   (NOTE for RESTful stores, a simple 20x
>   response is sufficient for the actions
>   "destroy" and "update".  The "create"
>   action should should return 200 along
>   with a database pk).

Now I've such response from server: `[{"tid": 5, "action": "CityGrid", "type": "rpc", "method": "create", "result": {"msg": "saved", "data": {}, }}]`

I guess that adding a database.pk of created object to server response should resolve problem but I've no idea how to do it. I've tried this `... "data": {"Id":my_object.id}` but with no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/writer/writer.html 
Creating return this:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "message":"Created record",
    "data": {"first":"sdfds","last":"sdfsdf","email":"asd@sdfs.sd","id":10}
}
```

So just return store record for new object in Reader.root property.

Comment: Also the data property may be array of records asnoticed Mchl. It is usable when data is saving in a batch.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `idProperty` of your JsonReader to the name of your PK. Also, I think that `data:` should be an array
`"data": [{"id": ....}]`
but I might be wrong :P

Comment: your advice is O.K - event is firing now. But the answer of Alerion is more usable - store will be updated with correct data when all fields are received, not only the pk.

Comment: And it doesn't need to be an array it seems ;)